# AWS Lambda scanning a dynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Im trying to scan a dynamodb table for all entries with prices between 1 and 13,

```
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();


exports.handler = function(event, context) {

  var params = {
    TableName: "hexagon2",
    ProjectionExpression: "price", 
    FilterExpression: "price between :lower and :higher",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
     ":lower": {"N": "1"},
     ":higher": {"N": "13"}
    }
};

  db.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // an error occurred
      } 
    else {
      console.log(data.Item); // successful response
      context.done(null,{"Result": "Operation succeeded."});
      }
  });
};
```

But I always get the following error, when I test it. I definatly have 'price' as a number attribute in my table and IAM is set up too.

```
START RequestId: f770c78b-93a1-11e6-b5f6-e5c31cef8b2d Version: $LATEST
2016-10-16T13:10:54.299Z    f770c78b-93a1-11e6-b5f6-e5c31cef8b2d    undefined
END RequestId: f770c78b-93a1-11e6-b5f6-e5c31cef8b2d
REPORT RequestId: f770c78b-93a1-11e6-b5f6-e5c31cef8b2d  Duration: 912.58 ms Billed Duration: 1000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 24 MB
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to reference `data.Item` which is `undefined`. Scan operations return a list, not a single item. That list would be referenced via `data.Items`

When in doubt, read [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property). Or you could just print out the entire `data` response to see the exact format of the response coming back.

Comment: That returns `[ { price: { N: '12' } }, { price: { N: '10' } } ]` (Which is the prices of the two items that meet the criteria, Not the whole items with their names etc. Why does it do this even though It get the whole `data.Items` ?

Comment: With DynamoDB you have to tell it what attributes you want back. If you want all the attributes back you need to add `Select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES"` to your `params` object. This is all spelled out clearly in the documentation. I really suggest you read the documentation. At the very least you should go here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property and look at all the parameters the `query` function takes and what each parameter does.