# How to query a dynamodb table for a range of attribute values in JavaScript using AWS sdk V3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sdk, amazon-dynamodb

I want to get the items from a dynamodb table which has recent (an attribute) value between 1 to 5. I'm writing my code for JavaScript and I am using AWS SDK V3.

I have an attribute "recent" which has values from 1 to 5.

```
   node.js
// Load the AWS SDK V3 files for JS
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { PutCommand, 
         BatchWriteCommand,
         DeleteCommand,
         UpdateCommand, 
         DynamoDBDocumentClient,
         paginateScan,
         ScanCommand,
         GetCommand } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";
import { unmarshall } from "@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb";

const log = (msg) => console.log(`[SCENARIO] ${msg}`);

const dynamodbClient = new DynamoDBClient({region: "eu-west"});
const dynamodbDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(dynamodbClient);


// Set a table name that we can use later on
const tableName = "my-database";

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
let articles = [];
    const paginatedScan = {
      TableName: tableName,
     // Scan uses a filter expression instead of a key condition expression. Scan will
     // read the entire table and then apply the filter.
      //ProjectionExpresion: "recent",
      FilterExpression: "#y between :y1 and :y2",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#y": {"S": "recent" }},
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":y1": {"N": "1"}, ":y2": {"N": "5" }},
      ConsistentRead: true,
      Select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
    };
    
    const command = new ScanCommand(paginatedScan);
    try {
    const response = await dynamodbClient.send(command);
    console.log(response.Items);
    } 
    catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    }
}
```

when I run this code, I expect to get a list of attributes for response but I don't get any list, I also noticed that the code gets stuck on `const response = await dynamodbClient.send(command);`, it doesn't go past that, I also don't get any error on the console, the code just shows successful and nothing else.

Note that I have seen a question regarding this for SDK V2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070568/aws-lambda-scanning-a-dynamodb-table) but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the document client, so your parameters should match that:

```
const paginatedScan = {
      TableName: tableName,
      FilterExpression: "#y between :y1 and :y2",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#y": "recent" },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":y1": 1, ":y2": 5 }
    };
```